# Add multiple events to the same layer in leaflet geoman

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet-geoman

I want to add multiple event listeners on the same map layer when the global edit button is toggled.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/xa9p3n24/2/) is a working example where I enable dragging and rotating on a layer.
I want to fire different events bases on the previous user interaction. This works fine for dragging and rotating.
Is there a way to make this work with resizing? I would like to allow the user to resize/drag/rotate a layer when the **pm:globaleditmodetoggled** is toggled.

```
map.on('pm:globaleditmodetoggled', ({ map }) => {
map.eachLayer((mapLayer) => {
  if (mapLayer instanceof L.Rectangle) {
    mapLayer.pm.enableLayerDrag();
    mapLayer.pm.enableRotate();
    mapLayer.on('pm:dragstart', ({ layer }) => {
      if (layer instanceof L.Rectangle) {
        layer.pm.disableRotate();
      }
    });
    mapLayer.on('pm:dragend', ({ layer }) => {
      if (layer instanceof L.Rectangle) layer.pm.enableRotate();
    });
    mapLayer.on('pm:rotateend', ({ layer }) => {
      if (layer instanceof L.Rectangle) {
        layer.pm.enableRotate();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

});